# Incorrect label text when using DisplayAttribute on metadata

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have created a metadata object for my entity for validation. The validation is working fine, but i'm having trouble with the display attribute. I would like to just have the display attribute on the metadata along with the validation attributes and have the correct text display for labels and error messages.

It seems like unless I specify the display attribute on the view model **and** the metadata object, I will get the incorrect text for either the label or the error message.

Is it possible to just define all of the necessary attributes in the metadata class and have everything brought forward to the view?

**Model:**

```
[MetadataType(typeof(Metadata))]
public partial class Contact
{
    class Metadata
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "FirstName", ResourceType = typeof(MyResources))]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
    }        

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

**View Model:**

```
public class ContactViewModel
{
    // Want to be able to omit all attributes from here
    //[Display(Name = "FirstName", ResourceType = typeof(MyResources))]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: can you post your meta data and model/viewmodel code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing something wrong here. It is the view model that should contain the presentation and validation attributes. It is the view model that gets displayed in the view, and because you have a different and specific view model for each view this is where you should use the Display attribute, in order to format it properly based on the requirements of this specific view.

As far as validation is concerned IMO this should also be performed on the view model. Why? Because you receive a view model from the view. Let's take for example the classic Insert/Edit views. You would have two different view models: `InsertItemViewModel` and `EditItemViewModel`. In the Edit view model the ID property will be required and thus marked with the Required attribute, but not in the Insert view model. Same stands for all formatting validation attributes such as StringLength, Regex, ...  => they should be on the view model.

As far as the model is concerned, your service layer which is responsible for manipulating it, should take care of [ensuring its validity](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/validating-with-a-service-layer-cs).

Comment: Thats true. But for instance a required field on an entity will be required when inserting and when editing. So I like the idea that you can set up your domain constraints at the domain layer (as it is a reflection of the database constraints `NOT NULL` etc). I would be happy to put the [Display] attribute in the view model but then it seems my error messages won't get the correct text.

Comment: @havok, well then good luck with putting view specific stuff on your models. I don't want to sound pessimistic here but you will need it.

Comment: i'm still struggling to understand why validation would be a view specific concern. This is something that is determined at the database level and has to be conveyed to the view but not determined by it. Each view will need to respect the same constraints and so to me it seems logical to have them at the domain level and brought forward to the view. If all validation is left up to the view then a constraint could easily be forgotten later when a new view is created. This also doesn't allow the domain project to be reused between solutions as readily.

Comment: @havok, of course, that's the reason why I pointed you to the [Validating with a Service Layer](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/validating-with-a-service-layer-cs) article. But before doing service layer validation think about what you get from the user => a view model. So validate this first. Then think of a service layer.

Comment: sorry, we seem to have been arguing parallel points as I forgot to mention one quite important factor. I have a custom `ModelValidatorProvider` which copies the validation attributes forward from the domain to the view model. So although i'm focusing on the domain it is in fact also part of my view.